# KeyBoard Layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using a laptop that has strange layout for the keyboard, for example 
'<' button exists beside '1' button.

I've tried many English layouts  like US, Canda, UK but it's none of these layouts, what could i do to determine the appropriate layout for my keyboard?

Comment: Maybe it would be easiest to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Good point.  ^^  Does your keyboard have a model number?

Comment: A Turkish keyboard has < beside 1 .

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do some strange setting to get French / English swaps;

This link [keyboards around the world](http://matadornetwork.com/abroad/the-ultimate-guide-to-computer-keyboards-around-the-world/) might help you identify its original locality.

Good luck!